# Image from Base64 does not display in WPF datagrid rows

Tags: wpf, powershell, datagrid

I'm trying with Powershell to add an icon at the beginning of each row in a WPF datagrid. I don't want to store the image so I use base64 to convert.

Here is the code that displays the datagrid with icon + process name :

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, System.Windows.Forms, System.Drawing
[xml]$xaml=@"
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Title="MainWindow" Height="410" Width="670" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
<DataGrid x:Name="dgResults" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Icon" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image x:Name="icon" Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="24" Height="24" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Process}" Header="Process" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'x:Name')]]") | ForEach-Object{
    Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Window.FindName($_.Name)
}

#start conversion
$strBase64 = [convert]::ToBase64String([System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe"))
$bitmap = New-Object System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage
$bitmap.BeginInit()
$bitmap.StreamSource = [System.IO.MemoryStream][System.Convert]::FromBase64String($strBase64)
$bitmap.EndInit()
$bitmap.Freeze()
#end conversion

$arrayItems = @()

Get-Process | Select-Object Name -First 5 | ForEach-Object{
    $itemObject = New-Object System.Object
    $itemObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Icon" -Value $bitmap
    $itemObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Process" -Value $_.Name
    $arrayItems += $itemObject
}

$dgResults.ItemsSource = $arrayItems

#Display Form
$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

The conversion of the Base64 String is done here :

```
#start conversion
$strBase64 = [convert]::ToBase64String([System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe"))
$bitmap = New-Object System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage
$bitmap.BeginInit()
$bitmap.StreamSource = [System.IO.MemoryStream][System.Convert]::FromBase64String($strBase64)
$bitmap.EndInit()
$bitmap.Freeze()
#end conversion
```

The `$bitmap` object returns `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`

When I change the Window logo with `$Window.Icon = $bitmap`, there's no problem, the icon is correctly set but when I store it and call the datas with `ItemsSource` from `$arrayItems` (that contains icon + process name), the images do not appear at the beginning of each row.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

---

### **Update with a function based on @ArcSet answer :**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, System.Windows.Forms, System.Drawing, System.IO
[xml]$xaml=@"
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Title="MainWindow" Height="410" Width="670" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
<DataGrid x:Name="dgResults" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Icon" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image x:Name="icon" Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="24" Height="24" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Process}" Header="Process" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'x:Name')]]") | ForEach-Object{
    Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Window.FindName($_.Name)
}

function ConvertTo-Icon{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][object]$Icon
    )

    $bmp = $Icon.ToBitmap()
    $stream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
    $bmp.Save($stream, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Png)
    $imageSource = [System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame]::Create($stream)

    # Set source here. Take note in the XAML as to where the variable name was taken.
    return $imageSource
}

$arrayItems = @()

Get-Process | Select-Object Name -First 5 | ForEach-Object{
    $itemObject = New-Object System.Object
    $itemObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Icon" -Value (ConvertTo-Icon -Icon ([System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe")))
    $itemObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Process" -Value $_.Name
    $arrayItems += $itemObject
}

$dgResults.ItemsSource = $arrayItems

#Display Form
$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: When loading a BitmapImage from a stream, you would usally close the stream after EndInit. This would require to set the BitmapImage's `CacheOption` to `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`. Although you aren't closing the stream, you do at least freeze the BitmapImage, which also requires that it's already loaded. So try to set CacheOption.

Comment: Hi Clemens I already tried with `$bitmap.CacheOption = "OnLoad"` before posting on SO but still no image displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this issue is with how WPF doesnt really support icon format. You need to covert that format into one readable by WPF Image tag. Use the code below instead. of what you are currently using

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, System.Windows.Forms, System.Drawing
[xml]$xaml=@"
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Title="MainWindow" Height="410" Width="670" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
<DataGrid x:Name="dgResults" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Icon" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image x:Name="icon" Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="24" Height="24" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Process}" Header="Process" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'x:Name')]]") | ForEach-Object{
    Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Window.FindName($_.Name)
}

#start conversion
$icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe")
$bmp = $icon.ToBitmap()
$stream = new-object System.IO.MemoryStream
$bmp.Save($stream, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Png)
$imageSource = [System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame]::Create($stream);
#end conversion

$arrayItems = @()

Get-Process | Select-Object Name -First 5 | ForEach-Object{
    $itemObject = New-Object System.Object
    $itemObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Icon" -Value $imageSource
    $itemObject | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Process" -Value $_.Name
    $arrayItems += $itemObject
}

$dgResults.ItemsSource = $arrayItems
#Display Form
$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

The difference is the conversion to PNG...

```
$icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe")
$bmp = $icon.ToBitmap()
$stream = new-object System.IO.MemoryStream
$bmp.Save($stream, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Png)
$imageSource = [System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame]::Create($stream);
```